# livequery is not working after WordPress 5.6 + update

Tags: jquery, wordpress, livequery

I am using [livequery 1.3.6.](https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/hazzik-jquery.livequery/1.3.6/jquery.livequery.js) When I updated WordPress 5.6+ version, it doesn't work. Can you help me to fix the issue. I am using in my javascript function like below code

```
$('#my-popup').livequery(function() {

    myFunc.load();

    $('#my-popup').closest('#TB_window').addClass('my-shortcodes-popup');

    $('.wp-color-picker-field').wpColorPicker({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                myFunc.loadVals();
                myFunc.cLoadVals();
            }, 1);
        }
    });
});
```

---

I am using it for visual shortcodes generator

When we click on link from dropdown, it options popup with shortcode options

1. https://paste.pics/C7VBO
2. https://paste.pics/C7VCK

It was working perfect with WordPress 5.5 but after update with 5.6 + it doesn't detect livequery and click events inside livequery functions

https://paste.pics/edit/C7VE4

I am using this livequery in below code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var myFunc = {
    loadVals: function() {
      var shortcode = $('#_my_shortcode').text(),
        uShortcode = shortcode;

      // fill in the gaps eg {{param}}
      $('.my-input').each(function() {
        var input = $(this),
          id = input.attr('id'),
          id = id.replace('my_', ''), // gets rid of the my_ prefix
          re = new RegExp("{{" + id + "}}", "g");
        var value = input.val();
        if (value == null) {
          value = '';
        }

        uShortcode = uShortcode.replace(re, input.val());
      });

      // adds the filled-in shortcode as hidden input
      $('#_my_ushortcode').remove();
      $('#my-sc-form-table').prepend('<div id="_my_ushortcode" class="hidden">' + uShortcode + '</div>');

    },
    cLoadVals: function() {
      var shortcode = $('#_my_cshortcode').text(),
        pShortcode = '';
      shortcodes = '';

      // fill in the gaps eg {{param}}
      $('.child-clone-row').each(function() {
        var row = $(this),
          rShortcode = shortcode;

        $('.my-cinput', this).each(function() {
          var input = $(this),
            id = input.attr('id'),
            id = id.replace('my_', '') // gets rid of the my_ prefix
          re = new RegExp("{{" + id + "}}", "g");
          var value = input.val();
          if (value == null) {
            value = '';
          }

          rShortcode = rShortcode.replace(re, input.val());
        });

        shortcodes = shortcodes + rShortcode + "\n";
      });

      // adds the filled-in shortcode as hidden input
      $('#_my_cshortcodes').remove();
      $('.child-clone-rows').prepend('<div id="_my_cshortcodes" class="hidden">' + shortcodes + '</div>');

      // add to parent shortcode
      this.loadVals();
      pShortcode = $('#_my_ushortcode').text().replace('{{child_shortcode}}', shortcodes);

      // add updated parent shortcode
      $('#_my_ushortcode').remove();
      $('#my-sc-form-table').prepend('<div id="_my_ushortcode" class="hidden">' + pShortcode + '</div>');

    },
    children: function() {
      // assign the cloning plugin
      $('.child-clone-rows').appendo({
        subSelect: '> div.child-clone-row:last-child',
        allowDelete: false,
        focusFirst: false,
        onAdd: function(row) {

          // Get Upload ID
          var prev_upload_id = jQuery(row).prev().find('.my-upload-button').data('upid');
          var new_upload_id = prev_upload_id + 1;
          jQuery(row).find('.my-upload-button').attr('data-upid', new_upload_id);

          // activate color picker
          jQuery('.wp-color-picker-field').wpColorPicker({
            change: function(event, ui) {
              myFunc.loadVals();
              myFunc.cLoadVals();
            }
          });
        }
      });

      //remove button
      $('body').on('click', '.child-clone-row-remove', function() {
        var btn = $(this),
          row = btn.parent();

        if ($('.child-clone-row').size() > 1) {
          row.remove();
        } else {
          alert('You need a minimum of one row');
        }

        return false;
      });


      // assign jUI sortable
      $(".child-clone-rows").sortable({
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        items: '.child-clone-row',
        cancel: 'div.fonticon, input, select, textarea, a'
      });
    },

    resizeTB: function() {
      var ajaxCont = $('#TB_ajaxContent'),
        tbWindow = $('#TB_window'),
        myPopup = $('#my-popup');

      tbWindow.css({
        height: window.my_thickBoxHeight,
        width: myPopup.outerWidth(),
        marginLeft: -(myPopup.outerWidth() / 2)
      });

      ajaxCont.css({
        paddingTop: 0,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingRight: 0,
        height: window.my_thickBoxHeight,
        overflow: 'auto', // IMPORTANT
        width: myPopup.outerWidth()
      });

      tbWindow.show();
      $('#my-popup').addClass('no_preview');
      $('#my-sc-form-wrap #my-sc-form').height(window.my_shortcodesFormHeight);

    },
    load: function() {
      var myFunc = this,
        popup = $('#my-popup'),
        form = $('#my-sc-form', popup),
        shortcode = $('#_my_shortcode', form).text(),
        popupType = $('#_my_popup', form).text(),
        uShortcode = '';

      // resize TB
      myFunc.resizeTB();
      $(window).resize(function() {
        myFunc.resizeTB()
      });

      // initialise
      myFunc.loadVals();
      myFunc.children();
      myFunc.cLoadVals();

      $('.my-input', form).change(function() {
        myFunc.loadVals();
      }); // update on value change

      // update upload button ID
      jQuery('.my-upload-button:not(:first)').each(function() {
        var prev_upload_id = jQuery(this).data('upid');
        var new_upload_id = prev_upload_id + 1;
        jQuery(this).attr('data-upid', new_upload_id);
      });
    }

  }

  // run
  $('#my-popup').livequery(function() {

    myFunc.load();
    $('#my-popup').closest('#TB_window').addClass('my-shortcodes-popup');

    // activate color picker
    $('.wp-color-picker-field').wpColorPicker({
      change: function(event, ui) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            myFunc.loadVals();
            myFunc.cLoadVals();
          },
          1);
      }
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', '.my-insert', function() {
    if (window.tinyMCE) {
      window.tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, $('#_my_ushortcode').html());
      tb_remove();
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Haven't seen that used for many many years since it's functionality was superseded by event delegation introduced into jQuery core. Seems to be missing an event name argument though. Can convert to using `on()` if you explain what you expect it to do

Comment: Thank you @ charlietfl for your best support. I added detail information about the code which I use for shortcode generator popup.

Comment: Any errors? I really forget how livequery works when events aren't included as arguments. It was mostly abandoned about 10 years ago. Are you familiar with what you expect it to do?

Comment: I didn't receive any errors because livequery doesn't detect any function. For example if i add alert('test'); inside function, it doen't work. ...... 

$('#my-popup').livequery(function() {  alert('test'); }